# How to install and use log4perl?

Tags: perl, log4perl

I am new to using `log4p` and want to use the same for logging in my code. I am getting errors like:

> Can't locate Log/Log4perl.pm in @INC

Which I understand is because of a missing library. Now, where and how do i get this library installed on my UNIX environment?

I tried installing:

```
yum install perl-Log-Log4perl-1.30-1.el6.noarch.rpm
```

This also failed. Am I not in the right track? Can someone give me a quick start up link which also tells how to install this package and from where?

Comment: Have you tried the `cpan` utility? `cpan Log::Log4perl`.

Comment: "This also failed" how?  What happened?

Answer (score 28):

The typical way to install packages for perl is to use [`cpan`](http://www.cpan.org/) or its variations (cpanm, cpanp, etc). If it is packaged by your distro thats easier/faster, but if it is not, you would still be able to do it via cpan.

```
cpan Log::Log4perl
```

OR in a DOS command prompt enter

```
> cpan
> install Log::Log4perl
```

You can look up the packages you want and their exact package names at [search.cpan.org](http://search.cpan.org/%7Emschilli/Log-Log4perl-1.40/lib/Log/Log4perl.pm)

Check [Wikipedia for information about CPAN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPAN)

Comment: Thanks Karthik, what does "cpan" do here

Comment: cpan is like yum but only for perl. It installs 3rd party packages. CPAN (in caps) is a collection of all 3rd party code that can be installed and used by programmers.

Comment: running this command , at the end it says: make has returned bad status , install seems impossible

Answer (score 1):

```
1) Go to http://search.cpan.org/~mschilli/Log-Log4perl-1.46/
2) Download tar.gz archive
3) tar zxfv archive
4) go to the archive's folder
5) run "perl Makefile.PL"
6) run "make"
7) run "make test"
8) run "make install"
```

that's all.